# Getting leaner but staying healthy

Tags: nutrition, body-fat, muscle-mass

I am on a 12 weeks transformation program and I passed 6 weeks. Vascularity has started to kick in, weight loss is happening, legs muscles can be felt esp quads and claves. So I guess belly fat is last. 
I have big day coming up in matter of weeks and I am getting a lot of comments that I am getting weak which can be bad coz I might loose fitting of my clothes. So my problem is I wanna get muscle or mass along with getting leaner. What should I do? 
Should I eat a lot? That will make the weight more or should I lift heavy? As I was going through program's,

> shortcut to size

I saw change in food and added supplements. So if I increase my food my current program will not work. As it's size of fist portion of protein and crabs. So what should I do,"?

EDIT : I want to gain muscle and get fuller look. While not getting weak.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you are asking. Are you losing weight so your clothes don't fit? Do you want to add muscle?

Comment: @inquisitiveIdiot I have edited the question, I wanna get fuller look, not look weak. While I get lean

Comment: How about you include what your shortcut to size program involves. Have you been trying to lose fat for the first six weeks of this program?

Comment: @inquisitiveIdiot yes. I can add but my body can hit a brick wall. (Not change)

Comment: As in you are not getting stronger anymore or you aren't losing weight? You will stop losing weight at some point as the weight you lose in fat you will gain in muscle

Comment: Here's my routine. I do intermittent fasting. I fast for about 16-18 hours a day. since I go to the office I eat  a decent meal 3hours before workout. and on the weekend I train fasted. Then eat when my feeding window comes. everyday = start eating 2 or 4pm and stops at 10pm. and be on a caloric deficit and have a mind and muscle connection every exercise. This works for "me" it may or may not work for you. just try what best works for you. side note I do take creatine post workout.

Answer (score 1):

Read [Burn the Fat, Feed the Muscle](http://www.burnthefatfeedthemuscle.com/) by Tom Venuto.

Disregard the unfortunate marketing strategy; it tends to come off as another "get ripped quick" scheme, but it's by far the most comprehensively researched, well-written and approachable take on the subject that I've come across. Note the extremely positive [reviews on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0804137846).

Venuto can explain things much better than I can, so I won't try to reproduce his message other than to briefly summarize:

- Building muscle and losing fat are conflicting goals.
- Only the most genetically-gifted among us can do both at once. However, everyone can either build muscle without also gaining excess fat, or lose fat without also losing muscle.
- Neither of the latter comes easily, and doing so requires disciplined and informed eating and exercise habits, along with setting (and sticking to) concrete goals.
- A starvation diet is counterproductive in almost every way. If you want to lose weight without losing muscle, you need to eat enough protein on a regular basis (ideally every 3 hours) to feed your muscles.
- Spreading out your meals and balancing macronutrients tames the insulin response, which controls fat gain and stabilizes your energy.

Hopefully that's enough to give you an idea of what the book is about. It should address your questions thoroughly.

(Incidentally, I'm in no way affiliated with Tom Venuto or the book. I just got a lot out of it, and enjoy recommending it to others.)

Comment: Incidentally, I'm in no way afiliated with my brother's grocery store. I just buy there from time to time, and enjoy recommending it to others.  ;)

Comment: I don't follow - is that meant to imply that I am getting something out of the endorsement?

Comment: Well, do you have any alternative litterature that's free to read?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should focus on your primary goal and don't stray away from that. You have a nice 12 week transformation and stick to it and complete that assignment first. it's not easy to change your body like Christian Bale does for his role and at times it can be outright dangerous. Get lean, get fit, get knowledgeable about nutrition and make it part of your daily life. Once you are done with your 12 week transformation then start getting serious about body building, hit the Gym and go for heavy compound exercise, start making diary of your routine and change your routine every 4-6 weeks to beat the plateau and muscle memory. Learn more about human body, physiology etc and set realistic goal like gaining 5 lbs of muscle mass in 6-8 weeks etc. It will require a lot of planning, focus and discipline. Stay motivated and hydrated :)